# Qt c++ class+subclass using Q_OBJECT doesn´t work

Tags: c++, qt

I`m having the hardest time in creating a class+subclass using Q_OBJECT:

I have a class *geometry* and some classes *Geo_1PF*, Geo_2,.. that inherit from geometry. I created those classes an everything worked well. Now I want to use QMetaType and for that I need to declare Q_Object. 
Once I used Q_OBJECT / Q_DECLARE_METATYPE my problems started.

I get the error **"undefined reference to vtable for ..."** 
I tried to delete all *.o and all moc_*.cpp before compiling again. I added **QT += core** in the *.pro-File but I didn`t succeed.

- **Do I have to put Q_OBJECT / Q_DECLARE_METATYPE in both the parent and the cild class?**
- **Why do I get that error ?**

Can somebody help me please?

This is my code:

```
geometry.h:

    #ifndef GEOMETRY_H
    #define GEOMETRY_H
    #include <QMetaType>        
    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QObject>   
    #include <QDebug>        

    class Geometry
    {
       // Q_OBJECT
    protected:

    public:
        Geometry();
        virtual ~Geometry(void) {}

        virtual void write_LNE(); 

    //Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geometry);
    #endif // GEOMETRY_H
```

-

```
geometry.cpp:

#include "geometry.h"

    Geometry::Geometry()
    { qDebug() << "Constructor:  hier ist Geometry";        }


    void Geometry::Haupt()
    {  qDebug() << " Das hier ist die Haupt von Geometry ....." ; }      
    void Geometry::write_LNE(){}
```

-

```
 Geo_1PF.h:

    #ifndef GEO_1PF_H
    #define GEO_1PF_H
    #include "geometry.h"

    class Geo_1PF : public Geometry
    {
       // Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Geo_1PF();
        ~Geo_1PF() {}

        virtual void write_LNE();        
    };

    //Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geo_1PF);
    #endif // GEO_1PF_H
```

- Geo_1PF.cpp:
       #include "Geo_1PF.h"

  ```
   Geo_1PF::Geo_1PF()
  {
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `Q_OBJECT` your class should inherites from `QObject` or its subclasses

```
class Geometry : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

//...
```

See [Using the Meta-Object Compiler (moc)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first)

Answer (score 2):

First, the `Q_OBJECT` macro **is not** inheritable. It must be included in every object that directly or indirectly inherits `QObject`. If your base class is `QObject` derived, then your derived class is also `QObject` derived, and thus must include the macro.

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT):

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class
>   definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other
>   services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

Second, `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` requires that the object has a copy constructor, and `QObject` doesn't support copy constructors **by design**, so it is impossible to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` with a `QObject` derived class. And it doesn't make sense either, because every `QObject` is automatically a meta type, since it is being processed by the meta object compiler. It will work if you declare a pointer to your type - `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geometry*)`. Registering a type as a meta type requires the type to have a copy constructor, if it doesn't you get an error.

From the looks of your classes, they **don't need** to derive from `QObject`, so you should not do that, you should remove the macro (and never use it if you are **not** inheriting a `QObject` or derived), and then `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geometry)` should work. It looks like you were under the impression you need `Q_OBJECT` to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` but in reality it is the opposite - the two are incompatible - the latter must have and the former must not have a copy constructor.